# как перенести управление wasd на андроид?Unity 3d C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Здраствуйте, я сделал управление машиной с помошью Input.GetAxis и не знаю как перенести на мобыльные устройста.Помогите пожалуйста
Вот код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class carMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float MotoForce;  // мощьность врощения задних колес
    public float SteerForce; // угол поворота передних колес
    public float BreakForce; // тормоз для передних колес
    public float ZADBreakForce; // тормоз для задних колес

    public float MaxSpeed; // максимальная скорость

    public WheelCollider WheelColliderPL; 
    public WheelCollider WheelColliderPP; 
    public WheelCollider WheelColliderZL; 
    public WheelCollider WheelColliderZP; 

    public Transform PLTransform;
    public Transform PPTransform;
    public Transform ZLTransform;
    public Transform ZPTransform;

    public GameObject PPL;
    public GameObject PPP;

    Vector3 TPL, TPP; // вектор поворота


    void Update()
    {
        float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * MotoForce; // ускорение колес
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * SteerForce; // угол поворот передних колес

        PLTransform.Rotate(WheelColliderPL.rpm / 60 * 360 * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        PPTransform.Rotate(WheelColliderPP.rpm / 60 * 360 * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        ZLTransform.Rotate(WheelColliderZP.rpm / 60 * 360 * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        ZPTransform.Rotate(WheelColliderZP.rpm / 60 * 360 * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        WheelColliderPL.motorTorque = v * MaxSpeed;
        WheelColliderPP.motorTorque = v * MaxSpeed;
        WheelColliderZL.motorTorque = v * MaxSpeed;
        WheelColliderZP.motorTorque = v * MaxSpeed;

        WheelColliderPL.steerAngle = h;
        WheelColliderPP.steerAngle = h;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            WheelColliderPL.brakeTorque = BreakForce;
            WheelColliderPP.brakeTorque = BreakForce;
            WheelColliderZL.brakeTorque = ZADBreakForce;
            WheelColliderZP.brakeTorque = ZADBreakForce;
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            WheelColliderPL.brakeTorque = 0;
            WheelColliderPP.brakeTorque = 0;
            WheelColliderZL.brakeTorque = 0;
            WheelColliderZP.brakeTorque = 0;
        }

        TPL = PLTransform.localEulerAngles;
        TPL.y = WheelColliderPL.steerAngle; // поворот коллайдера колеса
        PLTransform.transform.localEulerAngles = TPL; // поворот модели колеса

        TPP = PLTransform.localEulerAngles;
        TPP.y = WheelColliderPL.steerAngle;
        PPTransform.transform.localEulerAngles = TPP;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z))
        {
            transform.Rotate(new Vector3(180, 0, 0));
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Выдели свой инпут в отдельный интерфейс и взаимодействуй с ним.

Интерфейс:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public interface IPlayerInput
{
    event Action BrakeButtonPressed;

    Vector2 MovementDirection { get; }
}
```

И его реализации. KeyboardInput:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class KeyboardInput : MonoBehaviour, IPlayerInput
{
    public event Action BrakeButtonPressed;

    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _brakeButton = KeyCode.Space;

    public Vector2 MovementDirection => DefineDirection();

    private void Update()
    {
        WaitForBrakeButton();
    }

    private void WaitForBrakeButton()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(_brakeButton))
        {
            BrakeButtonPressed?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    private Vector2 DefineDirection()
    {
        var x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        var y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        return new Vector2(x, y);
    }
}
```

и MobileInput:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MobileInput : MonoBehaviour, IPlayerInput
{
    public event Action BrakeButtonPressed;

    [SerializeField] private Button _brakeButton = null;
    [SerializeField] private ScreenJoystick _joystick = null;

    public Vector2 MovementDirection => _joystick.Delta;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _brakeButton.onClick.AddListener(() => BrakeButtonPressed?.Invoke());
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        _brakeButton.onClick.RemoveListener(() => BrakeButtonPressed?.Invoke());
    }
}
```

Далее взаимодействуй с интерфейсом, а не конкретной реализацией:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SomeBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private MonoBehaviour _input = null;

    private IPlayerInput PlayerInput => (IPlayerInput)_input;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        if (_input is IPlayerInput) return;

        Debug.LogError($"{nameof(_input)} should implement {nameof(IPlayerInput)}");
        _input = null;
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        PlayerInput.BrakeButtonPressed += DebugBrake;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        PlayerInput.BrakeButtonPressed -= DebugBrake;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(PlayerInput.MovementDirection);
    }

    private void DebugBrake()
    {
        Debug.Log("Brake");
    }
}
```

То есть в твоем carMovement не должно быть проверок на нажатие кнопок / GetAxis и т.п. У тебя есть IPlayerInput, все взаимодействие через него.

Теперь абсолютно не важно с какой платформы ты играешь, можно в PlayerInput подставить что угодно, лишь бы оно реализовывало IPlayerInput.